# Scapy - cant send vlan tagged packet

Tags: scapy, vlan

I can sent a basic packet using scapy and inspect it on the receiving PC using wireshark. 
When I add a VLAN tag I cannot receive the packet or capture it in wireshark on the  origination side

> sendp( Ether()/IP(dst="172.16.64.49")/Raw(load="some data"))
>
> sendp( Ether()/Dot1Q(vlan=42)/IP(dst="172.16.64.49")/Raw(load="some data"))
>
> #### [Ethernet]
>
> dst= 00:15:17:e4:55:52
>     src= b0:83:fe:e2:df:b7
>     type= n_802_1Q
>
> #### [802.1Q}
>
> ```
>  prio= 0
>  id= 0
>  vlan= 42
>  type= IPv4
> ```
>
> #### [IP]
>
> ```
>     version= 4
>     ihl= 5
>     tos= 0x0
>     len= 29
>     id= 1
>     flags=
>     frag= 0
>     ttl= 64
>     proto= ip
>     chksum= 0x7c32
>     src= 172.16.102.92
>     dst= 172.16.64.49
>     \options\
> ```
>
> #### [Raw]
>
> ```
>        load= 'some data'
> ```

The data looks as i would expect in scapy, any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like two things happened, the Switches in my network discarded the outer VLAN, this i discovered when i sent a packet with double VLAN encapsulation. only one VLAN label showed up at the receiving side.

The second issue with the local Wireshark not showing the  packet sent was a wireshark filter mis-configuration